# How to convert JSON Array of Objects to Observable Array in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, observable, httpclient

I am calling a rest API from angular, the rest api returns data in  JSON Array of Objects like this
[image]

Now I am trying to convert it to my model class array but don't getting anywhere can you please guide me.

My Model Class

[image]

My Service File

[image]

Here it gives error on map and I don't know how to convert it to my model class array to display it in table

Comment: did you import map operator in the file where you use it? `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Answer (score 1):

Resolved It.

As i was directly getting the array of objects in response, I don't need to convert it and use an interface. So here is my correct code

```
fetchAllGamesRecord() : Observable<Fifa[]>{
    const fifaUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/fetchAllGamesRecord`;
    return this.httpClient.get<Fifa[]>(fifaUrl);
  }
```

This function is called like this

```
this.fifaService.fetchAllGamesRecord().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.allGameRecord = data;
        console.log(`Data = `+data);
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that while calling fetchAllGamesRecord

```
fetchAllGamesRecord().subscribe( (response: Fifa[]) => {
  // do something
}
```

where Fifa is interface not class

Comment: I didn't understood it can you please explain in more detail or can you write a pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

In the Spring framework also Fifa[] doesn't work in REST calls, we need to put it in another class as I showed below, I assume this will work.

```
export class FifaWrapper {
    wrapper: Fifa[];
}
```

and also use this class in Observable

```
fetchAllGamesRecord():  Observable<FifaWrapper> {
 ... do you handling here
}
```